# A program to create database models in Linux and Osx

Tags: database, linux, macos

Somebody knows a nice program for creating database models supporting Osx and Linux?

If possible for free, but a little amount of money is not an issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_%28software%29) is good.  I have used on Linux as well as Mac OS X.

Comment: Going to check it out now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks again! This program is free is good enough for the basic!